# Clip feature in QGIS doesn't return desired result

Tags: qgis, clip

I wanted to georeference a JPG map to get the shapefile of a city. I first uploaded the shapefile file of the entire state which had all the cities. then I georeferenced an existing JPG map of the state which had all the boundaries of all the cities in the states. Afterward, I created a new empty shapefile and edited it with polygons so I could get the boundary of the city I am interested in. The last thing I had to do was to clip the new file but I when clipped it I didn't get the desired results, as illustrated in the diagrams showing entire clipping procedure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you clip the large polygon by the small one, your output is correct. What output do you want?

Comment: thanks for your responses, that's exactly what I did, I clipped the large one by the small one...what I want is the output whose external boundary is the same as in the large one and not in the shape that I polygonize to.... does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As told, if you clip the large by the small, your output is correct.

So my guess is that you expected the same output shape without the inside linestrings ?
To do so, you have to clip the small one by the large one.
But what you will get is the small polygon. That you already have...

Comment: thanks for your responses, that's exactly what I did, I clipped the large one by the small one...what I want is the output whose external boundary is the same as in the large one and not in the shape that I polygonize to.... does it make sense?

Comment: In such case you have to use the difference tool with the large shape as input and the small one as difference layer.

Comment: Dear Basu thank you so much, i will definitely now explore "difference tool" as wel as I am new to QGiS.

Comment: as for my stated problrm, I eventualy got the right one, I changed my larger file( input file) to contain only the state I wanted the boundary of so it did the trick for me